# Why does $\langle \bar a \rangle \cap \overline K = \{\bar e \}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, p-groups

**Theorem** $:$ Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group. Let $a$ be an element of maximal order in $G.$ Then $\exists$ a subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $$G \cong \langle a \rangle \times K.$$

I have read the proof of this theorem from this [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Abelian_Group_of_Prime-power_Order_is_Product_of_Cyclic_Groups) article. At the very last paragraph of the proof it was stated that $\langle \bar a \rangle \cap \overline K = \langle\bar e \rangle$ where $\bar e = \langle b \rangle.$ Why is it so?

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: I think the proof of the structure theorem is done better in books on group theory.

Comment: @OliverJones do you also think that there are flaws in the proof provided in the link of Proof Wiki?

Comment: I don't think there are any mistakes; just redundancies. For example, the result you're asking about doesn't seem relevant. The proofs I've seen don't even mention it.

Comment: Which proof are you referring here? Can you please provide me the link where I can get a better proof?

Comment: Here's one reference: http://www.cs.xu.edu/math/math340/06f/11_FiniteAbelianGroups.pdf

Comment: Lemma 2 is what's relevant for you. It looks like that condition is needed but I think the proof is better.

Comment: I am sorry to say @OliverJones the link you provided can't be reached from my server. I don't know exactly what's happening in my server. Every time I try to reach that link it is shown that **Error : This site can't be reached**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101581/discussion-between-math-maniac-and-oliver-jones).